# Dual boot remove useless options, remove boot timer, run exe. on Kubuntu

Tags: boot, wine, kubuntu

Alright so I successfully installed both Kubuntu and W7.
When I start my laptop it offers several boot options like W7, Kubuntu, Kubuntu blabla and some other stuff.
I'd like to know If It is possible to only leave W7 and Kubuntu in the boot options. (Question 1)

Oh and If I don't choose an option in like 10 seconds Kubuntu will automatically start, can I remove the timer (?). Is it possible? (Question 2)

And since I removed Ubuntu (and installe K and W7), some of the laptop's drivers were removed. I managed to install all of them on W7, but not on K since I couldn't figure out how to install Wine in order to run the exe. files. Help? (Question 3)

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in 1 question. Please ask them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to question 1 and 2 is [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer) you can install it by running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

you can edit the entries under the 'List configuration' tab and the timeout under the 'general settings' tab.

for question 3 you need to be more specific about which drivers are missing and what hardware you have. maybe you can make a new question about it, that way the answers will be better focused.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The Wireless connection, Ethernet, Bluetooth, anything related to internet/communication drivers are missing.
My laptop is a Dell Vostro 2520, I'll edit the question with more info later on.

Comment: it is better to ask question 3 in a new question. I don't know the answer, most of the drivers should be in the kernel, and I believe that shouldn't change between Ubuntu and Kubuntu.